# Complex active records query for AJAX resource

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord, rails-activerecord

I have one select field for countries, a second select field for shipping options for a given country and when 1st country and 2nd shipping has been selected I would like to display the shipping cost.

When I load the shipping cart for the first time with show the shippingservices resource is correctly mapped for the first country (only the services for a specific weight and the selected country), but when I use the same query for the update_shipping action of the ajax resource I get `postzones.land_id = NULL`

My controller:

```
class CartsController < ApplicationController

  def show
    @cart = Cart.find(params[:id])
    @shippingservices = @cart.available_shipping_services.includes(:lands, :postzones).where('postzones.land_id = ?', Land.first.id)
  end

  def update_shipping
    @cart = Cart.find(params[:id])
    @shippingservices = @cart.available_shipping_services.includes(:lands, :postzones).where('postzones.land_id = ?', params[:land_id])
    respond_to do |format|
      format.js
    end
  end
end
```

In my carts model I have:

```
def available_shipping_services
  Shippingservice.where('weightmin <= ? and weightmax >= ?', total_weight, total_weight).where('shippingservices.shippingcarrier = ?', '1') 
end
```

The javascript AJAX part is thanks to @rewritten:

```
$(document).on("change", "#lands_select", function(event){
  $.ajax({
    url: "/carts/update_shipping/" + event.target.value,
    type: "GET"
  })
});
```

app/views/carts/update_shipping.js.erb is:

```
$("#shippingservices_select").empty()
  .append("<%= escape_javascript(render(:partial => @shippingservices)) %>")
```

and app/views/carts/_shippingservices.html.erb is:

```
<option value="<%= shippingservice.id %>"><%= shippingservice.name.titleize %></option>
```

When I try to make the ajax call I get:

```
Started GET "/carts/update_shipping/2" for 127.0.0.1 at Tue Dec 18 14:17:21 +0100 2018
Processing by CartsController#update_shipping as */*
  Parameters: {"id"=>"2"}
  Cart Load (0.4ms)  SELECT `carts`.* FROM `carts` WHERE `carts`.`id` = ? LIMIT 1  [["id", 5]]
  Cart Load (0.2ms)  SELECT `carts`.* FROM `carts` WHERE `carts`.`id` = ? LIMIT 1  [["id", "2"]]
  CartItem Load (0.4ms)  SELECT `cart_items`.* FROM `cart_items` WHERE `cart_items`.`cart_id` = 2
  SQL (0.9ms)  SELECT `shippingservices`.`id` AS t0_r0, `shippingservices`.`serviceID` AS t0_r1, `shippingservices`.`title` AS t0_r2, `shippingservices`.`name` AS t0_r3, `shippingservices`.`shippingcarrier` AS t0_r4, `shippingservices`.`length` AS t0_r5, `shippingservices`.`width` AS t0_r6, `shippingservices`.`height` AS t0_r7, `shippingservices`.`weightmin` AS t0_r8, `shippingservices`.`weightmax` AS t0_r9, `shippingservices`.`price` AS t0_r10, `shippingservices`.`created_at` AS t0_r11, `shippingservices`.`updated_at` AS t0_r12, `lands`.`id` AS t1_r0, `lands`.`name` AS t1_r1, `lands`.`partof` AS t1_r2, `lands`.`continent` AS t1_r3, `lands`.`area` AS t1_r4, `lands`.`CallingCode` AS t1_r5, `lands`.`ISOcode2` AS t1_r6, `lands`.`ISOcode3` AS t1_r7, `lands`.`created_at` AS t1_r8, `lands`.`updated_at` AS t1_r9, `postzones_shippingservices`.`id` AS t2_r0, `postzones_shippingservices`.`land_id` AS t2_r1, `postzones_shippingservices`.`shippingservicezone` AS t2_r2, `postzones_shippingservices`.`shippingservice_id` AS t2_r3, `postzones_shippingservices`.`created_at` AS t2_r4, `postzones_shippingservices`.`updated_at` AS t2_r5 FROM `shippingservices` LEFT OUTER JOIN `postzones` ON `postzones`.`shippingservice_id` = `shippingservices`.`id` LEFT OUTER JOIN `lands` ON `lands`.`id` = `postzones`.`land_id` LEFT OUTER JOIN `postzones` `postzones_shippingservices` ON `postzones_shippingservices`.`shippingservice_id` = `shippingservices`.`id` WHERE (weightmin <= 0 and weightmax >= 0) AND (shippingservices.shippingcarrier = 'Poste italiane') AND (postzones.land_id = NULL)
  Rendered collection (0.0ms)
  Rendered carts/update_shipping.js (3.2ms)
Completed 200 OK in 13ms (Views: 7.6ms | ActiveRecord: 1.8ms)
```

I suppose everything is set up correctly, but the controller is unable to resolve the active records query since he looks for `(postzones.land_id = NULL)`.

How can I get something like: postzones.land_id = Parameters: {"id"=>"2"}.
Which means all shippingservices which respect the weight of the cart for country with id: 2?

Thank you all in advance.

## UPDATE:

In my app/views/carts/show.html.erb I have the following form:

```
<%= form_for :cart, :url => {:action => "update_shipping"}, :html => { :method => "get", :remote => true } do |f| %>
  <%= f.select(:land_id, options_for_select(@lands.collect { |l| [l.name, l.id]}, 0), {}, {:prompt => "select a country", :id => 'lands_select'}) %><br>
  <%= f.select(:shippingservice_id, options_for_select(@shippingservices.collect { |s| [s.title.titleize, s.id] }, 0), {}, {:id => 'shippingservices_select', :prompt => "select a carrier"}) %><br>
  <%= f.submit "Calculate shipping" %><br>
<% end %>
```

The show page of the carts_controller shows the current shipping cart. The carts model knows its weight through carts_items. This permits me to calculate in the model the total_weight of the cart and make a query in the model which results in available_shipping_services, which I use in the show page to create successfully the first load, where for the fist entry all available solutions are displayed but every change after that results in a void second selector form.

The `{:action => "update_shipping"}` is probably wrong and has to be changed later to another action which should display the resulting shipping cost, but for now I was concentrating on getting the two select field working.

Thangs again!

Answer (score 1):

`params[:land_id]` is null, because you haven't passed it to the URL. You might want to pass it as query param (`GET "/carts/update_shipping/2?land_id=4"`) or even better pass it in the body of a POST request (for instance with a remote form)

Comment: @ Thank you. I will have to work on this one tomorrow and I will report back. My usual procedures do not work here. I usually use something such as `@image = Image.find(params[:id])` when I need to load images related to a given resource, but here something does not work.

Comment: I was able to get it running with `    @shippingservices = @cart.available_shipping_services.includes(:lands, :postzones).where('postzones.land_id = ?', params[:id])
` which was what I thought at the beginning, but somehow it did worked the second time I tried.